# Distributing points evenly spaced within a sphere

Tags: math

I am looking for an algorithm to distribute a bunch of points (could be anywhere from a few hundred to millions) within a sphere.  In this case the sphere is centered at (0,0,0).

For random points a simple method is

```
repeat
    x:=random*diameter-radius;
    y:=random*diameter-radius;
    z:=random*diameter-radius;
until ((x*x+y*y+z*z)<(radius*radius));
```

But I want to get the points evenly spaced within the sphere and without bunching at the poles.

Any good tricks/algorithms/formulas/code snippet to accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm. It looks like the algorithm you showed is a rejection algorithm, which should produce a uniform distribution over the interior of the sphere. Isn't that what you want? Perhaps I've misunderstood something.

Comment: The points are not evenly spaced within the sphere using that method.  Just randomly placed, so they all have different distances between each other.  I want to have all the points as close to equally spaced as possible.

Comment: These are 2 examples of 3000 points using the random method in my original post showing how they are not evenly spced.  https://ibb.co/Bj2rsz6 and https://ibb.co/D1FStcG

Comment: So, you are looking to space them regularly within the sphere, not necessarily randomly?

Comment: @Some1Else Assuming that you want more uniform spacing than random points, you might take a look at low-discrepancy sequences (also called quasirandom sequences). These are sequences of points which, by construction, are less "gappy" than random sequences. A web search for those terms should turn up some resources. What programming language are you working in?

Comment: Yes, uniform is what I need.  Quasi-random is better than random for uniformity but still not evenly spaced from what I can see.  Maybe I will have to use an initial random distribution and then some way of iterating over the points moving them apart from closest neighbors until they are spaced uniformly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need evenly spaced points - just place them in grid nodes.

Sphere with radius R has volume

```
 V=4/3*Pi*R^3
```

so for placing N points every cell of cubic grid *(perhaps you might want to use hexagonal close packing)* should have volume

```
v=4/3*Pi*R^3/N
```

and edge length

```
l = R * (4*Pi/(3*N))^1/3
```

Then generate points in coordinates `(a*l, b*l, c*l)` where `a,b,c` are integers limited by `-R..+R` (with appropriate sum of squares).

---

Proposed approach is quite rough estimation and perhaps some points from N needed ones might run outside of the sphere. In this case one have to diminish cell size or use more exact value - it might be calculated using 3D analog of [Gauss circle formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html)  ()

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

- Put the center of your sphere at a random position within an infinite volume of evenly-spaced points, like a tetrahedral or cubic lattice.
- Enumerate points in order of increasing distance from the center until you have the right number.
- Rescale the selected points around the center so that the distance to the furthest point is equal to the desired radius.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation by [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki). The above formula has been explained in [proof of the formula mentioned](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html). But the formula has some limitations. The cube length can be 2 (-1 to 1 in all directions). From the above concept, mentioned by [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) or [proof of the formula mentioned](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html) we can generalize for the cube of any length (i.e 2a (-a to a in all directions)). Here 2a is the side length of the cube.

$a^6-(a^2-x^2 )(a^2-y^2)(a^2-z^2)=x^2 a^2 (a^2-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^2 z^2}{3a^2})+y^2 a^2 (a^2-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2 z^2}{3a^2})+z^2 a^2 (a^2-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^2 x^2}{3a^2})$

$x'=xa \sqrt{a^2-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^2 z^2}{3a^2}}$,

$y'=ya \sqrt{a^2-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^2 z^2}{3a^2}}$,

$z'=za \sqrt{a^2-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^2 x^2}{3a^2}}$,

From the above equation, we can easily separate the (x',y',z') as explained in 1. The above equation will readily find the mapping of the generalized length of the cube to a sphere. I hope this will be helpful.

Form the above equation we can also find the evenly distribution of points within the sphere by varying the grid size of the cube. By discretizing the cube into different grids and simultaneously mapping into the sphere will give the evenly distribution of points within the sphere.

Kindly ignore some typos.

C++ code for evenly distributing points within the sphere:-

```
for(x=-a;x<=a;x=x+n)
for(y=-a;y<=a;y=y+n)
{
    for(z=-a;z<=a;z=z+n)
    {
        xnew=x*a*(sqrt((a*a)-(y*y)/(2)-(z*z)/(2)+(y*y*z*z)/(3*a*a)));
        ynew=y*a*(sqrt((a*a)-(z*z)/(2)-(x*x)/(2)+(x*x*z*z)/(3*a*a)));
        znew=z*a*(sqrt((a*a)-(x*x)/(2)-(y*y)/(2)+(y*y*x*x)/(3*a*a)));
        cout<<" "<<xnew<<" "<<ynew<<" "<<znew<<endl;
        }
}
    }
```

Note:- Here in code, n is the grid size of a cube.